# Batch file IF GEQ triggers despite not matching

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm trying to start and .exe at a certain time frame, but despite not matching GEQ yet (e.g. 20:55), it still goes to the :run label.

I've also tried only EQU, but here, despite matching the time, it doesn't goto :run. Only if i start the batch at the exact %time%, it works, but obviously that's missing the whole point.

Whats wrong here?

```
@ECHO OFF
SET hour=%time:~0,5%
echo It is %hour%

:check
echo.
echo %time:~0,5%
echo checking
timeout /t 60
IF %hour% GEQ 21:00 IF %hour% LEQ 22:00 (goto :run) else (goto :check)

:run
echo running
start chrome.exe
pause
```

Comment: That is not a number. You only can do maths on integers (ie whole numbers in range of - 2 billion to + 2 billion). See `set /?` (at other times `for /?` may be better but not here) on how to chop up strings.

Comment: Replace `IF %hour% GEQ 21:00 IF %hour% LEQ 22:00 (goto :run) else (goto :check)` with `IF %hour% GEQ 21:00 IF %hour% LEQ 22:00 (goto :run)` and a new line `goto :check` (and maybe add another `timeout` before)

Comment: Although you are not comparing numbers but strings (due to the `:`), the comparison works as you have got fixed-length strings. However, execution continues at the next line when `IF %hour% GEQ 21:00` evaluates false. You could however add another `else` clause, like this: `IF %hour% GEQ 21:00 (IF %hour% LEQ 22:00 (goto :run) else (goto :check)) else (goto :check)`. Anyway, note that `%time%` returns the current time in a locale-dependent manner, so this works only in case you use 24h-time format (not AM/PM)...

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try something like this:

```
@echo off

:get_the_time
for /f %%# in ('wMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get /Format:value') do @for /f %%@ in ("%%#") do @set %%@

echo CURRENT TIME -- %hour%:%minute%
:: creatring a comparable number with wich time for starting chrome can be used
if %hour% LSS 10 ( set hour=10%hour% ) else ( set hour=1%hour%)
if %minute% LSS 10 (set minute=0%minute%)

set comparable_time=%hour%%minute%

::now the comparable_time is in format 1HourMinute . The 1 in the front is to avoid complications with leading zero

timeout /t 60
if %comparable_time% GEQ 12100 if %comparable_time% LEQ 12200 ( goto :run ) else ( goto :get_the_time )

:run
echo running
start chrome.exe
pause
```

As your method of getting time is not so robust and depends on the time settings in the control panel I preferred using the [WMIC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203090/how-do-i-get-current-datetime-on-the-windows-command-line-in-a-suitable-format/19799236#19799236).

When there are non numerical symbols in the things you want to compare with IF it will make an alphabetical comparison so the `:` is not part of the IF clauses now.

Also a comparison is made with variable looking like *1**Hour**minute* and the hour and minutes are kept in two digits format so now only a comparisons with numbers without leading zeros are used.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy enough to handle dates in PowerShell. Create two files in the same directory.

=== runitat.ps1

```
$h = (Get-Date).Hour
if (($h -ge 20) -and ($h -le 21)) {
    Invoke-Command -Command {& "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"}
}
```

=== runitat.bat

```
:head
powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -File %~dp0runitat.ps1
timeout /T 60
GOTO head
```